# C# LINQ and XML Parsing with Separate Sections

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am having a bit of trouble with a program I am trying to write. It is going to be using XML files that are generated by another program, so the formatting will always be the same, but number of sections and data within a section will be different, and I am trying to make it universal.

Here is a sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hcdata>
  <docTitle>Test Health check</docTitle>
  <sections>
    <section id="1" name="server-overview">
      <h1>Server Overview</h1>
      <table name="server1">
        <th>Field</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <tr>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td>TestESXI1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>RAM</td>
          <td>24GB</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table name="server2">
        <th>Field</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <tr>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td>TestESXI2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>RAM</td>
          <td>16GB</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </section>
    <section id="2" name="vms">
      <h1>Virtual Machine Information</h1>
      <table name="vminfo">
        <th>VM Name</th>
        <th>RAM Usage</th>
        <tr>
          <td>2K8R2</td>
          <td>2048MB</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2K12R2</td>
          <td>4096Mb</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </section>
  </sections>
</hcdata>
```

And here is some C# code I have been messing around with to try and pull values:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace XMLParseDev
{
    class XMLParseDev
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int sectionCount = 0;
            Console.WriteLine(sectionCount);

            XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\test.xml");
            //XElement xEle = XElement.Load(@"C:\users\test.xml");
            //Application winWord = new Application();

            IEnumerable<XElement> xElements = xDoc.Elements();
            IEnumerable<XElement> xSectionCount = from xSections in xDoc.Descendants("section") select xSections;
            IEnumerable<XElement> xthCount = from xth in xDoc.Descendants("th") select xth;

            foreach (XElement s in xSectionCount)
            {
                //This is to count the number of <section> tags, this part works
                sectionCount = sectionCount + 1;

                //This was trying to write the value of the <h1> tag but does not
                IEnumerable<XElement> xH1 = from xH1Field in xDoc.Descendants("h1") select xH1Field;
                Console.WriteLine(xH1.Attributes("h1"));

                foreach (XElement th in xthCount)
                {
                    //This was supposed to write the <th> value only for <th> within the <section> but writes them all
                    Console.WriteLine(th.Value);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sectionCount);
        }
    }
}
```

And the output:

```
0
System.Xml.Linq.Extensions+<GetAttributes>d__1
Field
Value
Field
Value
VM Name
RAM Usage
System.Xml.Linq.Extensions+<GetAttributes>d__1
Field
Value
Field
Value
VM Name
RAM Usage
2
```

Basically what I want to do, is convert the XML to a Word document (this question isn't about the Word part, just the data getting). I've used tags similar to HTML to assist with ease of design.
I need each `<section>` tag to be processed as an individual part.
I planned on running through so I can get counts of table rows and columns, so the table can be created and then populated (as the table needs to be made with the right dimensions first).
The section will also have a heading (`<h1>`).

I planned on this running as a loop that would be a foreach that loops sections and does everything else within this section in the iteration, but I can't figure out how to lock the data selection down to just a specific section.

Hope this makes sense and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if you might find it easier to let a DataSet parse the data into DataTables then pick which tables you want the data from.  Here's a little snippet that will read the xml file and display all the data as tables:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml("xmlfile2.xml");
foreach(DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Table Name - {dt.TableName}\n");
    foreach(DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
    {
        Console.Write($"{dc.ColumnName.PadRight(16)}");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {

        foreach(object obj in dr.ItemArray)
        {
            Console.Write($"{obj.ToString().PadRight(16)}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.WriteLine(new string('_', 75));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this and see how it goes